# Passing servlet config parameters under Servlet spec 3.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

When using annotations instead of a web.xml file, what do you do with the servlet init/config parameters that you can normally read from the [ServletConfig](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html) object? ie

```
@WebFilter("/sample")
public class MyServlet {

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        String value = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("key");
        // or
        value = getServletContext().getInitParameter("key");
    }
}
```

or in the case of a filter:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    public void init (FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        filterConfig.getInitParameter("key");
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:** I know you can hardcode configuration parameters in an annotation, but I dont want to hardcode configuration settings into the code. For example, this servlet could not be shared between two applications:

```
@WebFilter("/sample", initParams = {@InitParam(name = "database_host", value = "blah.com")})
public class MyServlet {

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        String value = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("database_host");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is any middle ground here, either make of use the web.xml or the annotations.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @WebServlet(name = "TestServlet", urlPatterns = {"/test"},
 initParams = {@WebInitParam(name="key", value="value")})

 public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {        
      String key= getInitParameter("key");
   }
 }
```

**EDIT:**

To answer you updated question, you have two options:

1. Use the old pattern of using `web.xml` based init params
2. Just create a dummy extension(subclass) of the servlet in the other project and assign new init params.

Comment: Wouldn't hardcoding server and or application dependent configuration settings be bad practice?

Comment: As long as I understand, annotation are replacing configurations done through `xml` files earlier. Same here. Earlier this was going in `web.xml` file, now it is maintained in the servlet itself. **Treat annotations as configurations**. Good part of using annotations is that "all related info is now maintained in same file instead of browsing through multiple files". If you want to use the old pattern for some specific reason, its still good and valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean

```
@Servlet(urlMappings={"/MyApp"}, initParams ={@InitParam(name="lang", value="english")})
public class MyServlet {
```

You can refer to this [An Introduction To Servlet 3.0](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/10/14/introduction-to-servlet-3.html?force=893)

Comment: Wouldn't hardcoding server and or application dependent configuration settings be bad practice?

Comment: including a web.xml (in tomcat at least) stops the annotations working.

Comment: @Jacob: What is the servlet version specified on your web.xml?